# Keep node/user tabs in one language

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have 3 languages in my site and also user with 'Webmaster' role.

Is it possible to keep all nodes/users tabs (view|edit|translate|devel etc.) in one preferred language for this role?

Comment: please provide more details about what you want to do. by default this tabs exists

Comment: @zhilevan they exists, that's right. But my question is how to keep them in 1 (one) preferred language regardless on what language you are. E.g.: I want all my tabs in English even if I switch to German.

Answer (score 1):

What you want, as I understand you, is to have a fixed interface language for a certain role.

You can adjust the user interface text language in *admin/config/regional/language/configure*. Unfortunately there's no method based on role. You can only use the user method, so users see the interface in their prefered langauge. This setting is for all users, not just for a role.

You may code a new language detection method based on role, but I don't know where you have to start (except checking the i18n module code).